# Unable to get the square brackets for the single individual records while using the json_agg inside the json_compose in Teradata-sql-assistance

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

According to the documentation,
if we have the following data in a table named emp_table

```
   empID         company       empName       empAge
     1,        'Teradata',    'Cameron',       24 
     2,        'Teradata',    'Justin',        34 
     3,        'Apple',       'Someone',       34
```

and if we use the following query :

> ```
> SELECT JSON_Compose(T.company, T.employees)
> FROM
>  (
>   SELECT company, JSON_agg(empID AS id, 
>      empName AS name, 
>      empAge AS age) AS employees
>   FROM emp_table
>   GROUP BY company
>  ) AS T;
> ```

we are supposed to get :

```
JSON_Compose
------------
{
  "company" : "Teradata",
  "employees" : [ 
     { "id" : 1, "name" : "Cameron", "age" : 24 },
     { "id" : 2, "name" : "Justin", "age" : 34 }
  ]
}
{
  "company" : "Apple",
  "employees" : [ 
     { "id" : 3, "name" : "Someone", "age" : 24 } 
  ]
}
```

But when I try to follow the same steps, I'm not able to get the square bracket for the individual records.
The result I'm getting is :

```
JSON_Compose
------------
{
  "company" : "Teradata",
  "employees" : [ 
     { "id" : 1, "name" : "Cameron", "age" : 24 },
     { "id" : 2, "name" : "Justin", "age" : 34 }
  ]
}
{
  "company" : "Apple",
  "employees" : 
     { "id" : 3, "name" : "Someone", "age" : 24 } 
}
```

Is there any way to get square bracket for individual records as well ?

Comment: Same thing happens to me, that sure looks like a bug.

Comment: Any idea what can be done in such cases? will this get fixed automatically or do we have to do something?

Comment: I believe this is a _documentation_ error but intended behavior. JSON_AGG returns an array when there are multiple objects in the group, but not when there is a single object. JSON_PUBLISH always returns an array when aggregation is requested, even if the array contains a single object.